Flutter: Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
When trying to run my flutter project i get this error:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:954)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:761)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling0(HttpURLConnection.java:2205)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2167)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1687)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1611)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

List of things i tried:

updated Android Studio
updated Flutter
updated gradle distribution to the latest version in gradle-wrapper.properties

What is causing this issue?

Can you create another empty project to see if it can run without any change to the project?

Have you seen java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
Most probably you are having network / internet issue.

I already fixed the issue yesterday, thank you all. All I did was run gradle offline by setting the distribution url of my "distributionurl" in gradle-wrapper.properties to the file location of the manually downloaded gradle distribution folder
Then in the gradle.properties I file I added: "org.gradle.offline=true"
gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=file:///C:/Gradle/gradle-8.9/gradle-8.9-bin.zip

gradle.properties:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.offline=true

This was how I fixed the issue. Chat GPT and Meta AI was a major hand in helping me figure it out. I think my server can't connect to the service.gradle.org website because of my location, where it initially is supposed to download the files, which was why it returned the end of file error. I ended up using a VPN to download the distribution "gradle-8.9-bin.zip" manually. I hope this helps anyone going through the same issue
